# Peugeot 307 multiple error codes, same cause?

Tags: electrical, electronics, peugeot-307

My sister was driving her driving her Peugeot 307 XS 1.6 2006 the other day, and out of nowhere all these error messages start popping up on her screen.

It started with "*Battery charge or electrical supply faulty*" then "*Airbag[s] or protective seat belt[s] faulty*" and "*ABS breaking system faulty*". The lights for ABS, airbags, ESP and the warning light turned on and eventually so did **STOP**. At that point the power steering system stopped working.

We've checked all the fuses and I doubt all these different systems would fail within about 5 minutes of driving. Any ideas on what it could be?

**EDIT:** Hey. Turns out there wasn't a serpentine belt at all, must have broken right before the issues started. Recharged the battery with a reconditioning charger. Just replaced it and the alternator is putting out 14.25 V but the lights and warnings still pop up. Do we need to reset them somehow? Or is there something else causing the issues now?

Comment: It sounds like the alternator may have stopped worked, which caused the battery to drain, which would then show as you suggested. First place to look is the serpentine belt. If the alternator isn't spinning, it isn't charging.

Comment: Hey. Turns out there wasn't a serpentine belt at all, must have broken right before the issues started. Recharged the battery with a reconditioning charger. Just replaced it and the alternator is putting out 14.25 V but the lights and warnings still pop up. Do we need to reset them somehow? Or is there something else causing the issues now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the alternator may have stopped worked, which caused the battery to drain, which would then show as you suggested. First place to look is the serpentine belt. If the alternator isn't spinning, it isn't charging.

As for the lights, yes you will most likely need to get them reset. Here in the States we'd take it to one of the retail parts stores and they'd be able to do it for us. In Sweden, I'm not sure if you'd have the same opportunity. Check with some of your larger parts places as they would hopefully have a scanner which would be able to reset them for you. If that fails, you could take it in to a Peugeot dealership, but they'd most likely charge you money to do it.

Comment: Managed to do it with my own obd2 connector. Driven it 230 km and it works great now. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Kajsa - Yes, should have thought you could do it with your own scanner, but made a bad assumption per what you stated. Great you have it fixed!